# Не ловит try catch AngleSharp

Tags: c#, anglesharp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Вот код, вылетает ошибка System.NullReferenceException, а try catch не ловит её

```
 var opisanie = document.QuerySelector("div.goods_des");

                        Size = document.QuerySelector("select#size-s");
                        var container = document.QuerySelector("div.tb-item");
                        Number = container.QuerySelector("img");
                        var ss = container.QuerySelectorAll("img");
                        int y = 0;
                        foreach (var allo in ss)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(y++);
                            Console.WriteLine(allo.GetAttribute("src").ToString());
                        }


                        Console.WriteLine($"sdasdasd {Size.TextContent}");
                   Console.WriteLine($" Описание:{Number.GetAttribute("alt").ToString()} sss");
                    try
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($" Описание:{opisanie.TextContent} sss");

                    }
                    catch (System.NullReferenceException)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Упс.. Описания нету...");

                        continue;
                    }
```

Comment: скорее всего потому, что код с ошибкой не внутри `try..catch`

Comment: может ошибка в `Number` или `Size`?

Comment: Нет, именно там где я отлавливаю, сейчас скриншот добавлю

Comment: @Grundy,@Виталий Шебаниц, Ответ обновил

Comment: на скриншоте все ок - при продолжении выполнения зайдет в catch

Comment: а если сделать  "F11 — это команда Шаг с заходом" что происходит на след. шаге?

Comment: @Grundy я убрал точку останова,так же не ловит

Comment: Поставь точку остановки внутри catch

Comment: @RomanOnofreichuk выделяет желтым `catch (System.NullReferenceException)`

Comment: @Grundy поставил внутри, все осталось так же

Comment: @PrinceTag, что так же? :) он останавливается?

Comment: Он ошибку выдает перед catch, как и на скриншоте

Answer (score 0):

Проблемма была в том, что у меня стоит галочка "Остановить, при возникновении исключения этого типа"